# how to map string to enum in swift

Tags: swift, swiftui, enums

I have a array of strings and a function that implemented from walletCore (https://github.com/trustwallet/wallet-core). I receive `String` from server  like this : "ETH", "BTC" and .... . and the function I am using from walletCore is like this :

```
AnyAddress.isValid(string: "blockChain address", coin: .bitcoin)
```

I want to map this strings from array to coin Enum from this function to validate my blockchain addresses.

here is my code:

```
import SwiftUI
import WalletCore


struct TestCoreWallet: View {
   @State private var networkCoins = ["ETH", "BTC", "LTC", "XMR"]
   @State private var isvalid: Bool = false
 var body: some View {
   Text(isvalid ? "true" : "false")
     .onTapGesture {
           isvalid = core()
        }

}
  func core() -> Bool {
  return AnyAddress.isValid(string: "sampleblockchainaddress", coin: .bitcoin)
}
```

I want to use networkCoins instead of default enum in isValid func or map the strings to that enum or any way that I can validate my address with my strings.

Answer (score 1):

As you did not post your enum I can only give a more general solution:

The initializer for an enum that derives from a particular value is `Enum(rawValue: ...)` so your enum should look like:

```
enum Coin: String{
    case bitcoin = "BTC",
    case eth = "ETH",
    ......
}
```

Then you can map your `String` to an enum with `Coin(rawValue: "ETH")` this would give your the `.eth` case.